# DataGridView - WinForms - Header text wraps too soon

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView, and I want my columns to be as small as they can be so I can fit a lot of  columns on. However, I'm finding that the columns wrap when they don't need to.

Does anyone know how to work around this? I've tried looking at the Padding properties on the column.HeaderCell.Style property but it's actually set to 0 already, so I'm confused!

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're not considering the space needed to show the sort direction glyph. If you set a Column's `.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable`, that space is reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

To change a whole row:

```
 dataGridView.Rows[0].DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

To change a column:

```
 dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

To change a single cell:

```
 dataGridView[0, 2].Style.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Change wrapmode:

```
dataGridView.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```